# What is the best way to create/build Scala Project

Tags: eclipse, scala, intellij-idea

I started learning Scala lately. I find it extremely difficult to -productively- add new project. I was using Visual Studio for years as I am coming from .net development environment.

However, SBT is great tool to build Scala project, but you have to make everything from scratch by your own. It's sometime non productive to make a project that respect the guide lines of Scala () add plugins.build,

I found many alternatives, but I am not sure if these projects are updated:

1- jrebel 
http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/jrebel.html

2- TypeSafe Templates:
http://typesafe.com/activator/templates

3- Using giter8
github.com/n8han/conscript

IDEs lack some feature such as supporting Akka, in addition to that:
for Eclipse, in the project folder, type sbt eclipse,
for Intellij IDEA, in the project folder, type sbt gen-idea

What is the best way to create and build Akka projects in an interactive way, respecting the guideline of the scala (You can see here the project's architecture www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/project-structure.html)

Comment: With a little practice, you can get quite fast at new Scala project development with sbt: http://vimeo.com/75100243

Comment: Thanks @James : Did you try to build Maven Project with Scala before.